# How to tell if variable is true false when its assigned a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

a variable `asset` is assigned the following value: `:app` or `:device`

How do i check whether the value of `asset` is `:app` or `:device`?

Thanks

Comment: why not `asset == :app` ? http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Symbol.html#method-i-3D-3D

Comment: ...oh duh. I had that, but had an error else where looking for `app.id` when there clearly wasnt one. Thanks!

Comment: This is often written, `if(asset = :app)...`, resulting in grief. An alternative to `asset == :app` is to use [String#eql?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-eql-3F): `asset.eql?(:app)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if asset == :app
  #code
elsif asset == :device
  #code
end
```

Comment: This would be a case for the `case` statement.